# How to keep original ID using UUID as primary key in Django RF project?

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, uuid

I'd like to use two different primary keys in my DRF database app. By default Django "create" id as PK but when I'm trying to define new field in model (uuid = models.UUIDField (primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False), default id field is not defined (in DB exist only uuid).

How can I initialize both of them?

I can mention that I didn't define id field in my model because it is (or should be - as I suppose) adding by DRF.

```
class Store(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, 
editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Comment: instead of setting primary_key as True set unique as True. That would be the standard way of having two unique fields.

Comment: @5parkp1ug it's partly good solution because it works but i'd like to use uuid as foreign key in other model. Is it possible to connect e.g. Product (Model) field `storeUUID = models.ForeignKey(Store)` even if uuid isnt PK but only unique ?

Comment: your UUID field is unique you could always use **to_field** argument. Check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field)

Answer (score 1):

## Primary key

In the relational model of databases, a primary key is a specific choice of a minimal set of attributes (columns) that uniquely specify a tuple (row) in a relation (table).

So, you can either use default primary key `id` or `uuid` (your choice).

If you want both then use `unique=True` instead.

```
class Store(models.Model):
  uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
  url = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=False)
  country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

For your case you can change your model as

```
from django.db.models.fields import AutoField
from django.db.models.fields import checks
from django import models

class AutoFieldNonPrimary(AutoField):

    def _check_primary_key(self):
        if self.primary_key:
            return [
                checks.Error(
                    "AutoFieldNonPrimary must not set primary_key=True.",
                    obj=self,
                    id="fields.E100",
                )
            ]
        else:
            return []

class Store(models.Model):
      id = models.AutoFieldNonPrimary(unique=True)
      uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
      url = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=False)
      country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Comment: You're right, it works correctly but i'd like to use Store uuid as foreign key in different model. Could u give me some advice how i can do this?

Comment: Unfortunately AutoField raise error `core.Store.id: (fields.E100) AutoFields must set primary_key=True.` In addition, when i was trying to remove uuid field and leave only ID as autoField (for test purpose) it saise another error `AssertionError: Model core.Product can't have more than one AutoField.`

Comment: @Poul3R why do you need `id` you already have `uuid` as `pk` ?

Comment: Some views, models and serializers are using current id but i dont want to rewrite all of them right now. New one should be based on uuid instead of simple id that's why i need both of them. Have you any other idea how to solve it?